# Key Image and Ring Member

Tags: daemon, ring-signatures, key-image

When were counting the number of ring signatures for a certain transaction do we count the number of key images or ring members of each key image?

Answer (score 1):

Monero transactions have a multi-layered ring signature.

This multi-layered ring signature has one or more rings.

There is a ring for every real output being spent. Each of these rings will have the same number of ring members, known as the ring size. These ring members are references to public keys of outputs on the blockchain (sometimes referred to as one-time output public keys or stealth addresses). Ring members which are not the real output being spent are known as decoys. An older term for the number of decoys per ring is "mixin", and therefore mixin = ring size - 1.

For every ring, there is a key image. Therefore the number of key images per transaction is the same as the number of real outputs being spent in the transaction. Each key image anonymously identifies the real output being spent in each ring, and prevents double-spends. There is only one real output being spent per ring.

Comment: is there a way to get the data for ring signatures? i am trying to use https://src.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions 
To get the signatures.. But i was wondering if they are the correct data or not?

Comment: @Sridavei what do you mean by "get the data"? What information are you specifically interested in about the ring signatures?

Comment: i want to collect the ring signatures for all the transactions in monero.. I want to do some analysis on that

Comment: @Sridavei I don't think you actually want all of the ring signature data. You want perhaps the references to outputs being spent, or the ring size, etc right? That information is available in the link you posted as "vin - List of inputs into transaction:"

Comment: i really want to collect all the ring signatures to that transactions. Is the signatures in that output the correct ring signatures for that transaction??

Comment: @Sridavei I don't understand your question. This is off-topic for the main question, so please open a new question about how to do this.